# How to load .PDF file directly as initialDoc without using XOD in PDFtron

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below i mentioned a sample code what i am using in our application,if we are loading .XOD file through initialDoc: "GettingStarted.xod" working file.If we change .xod to .pdf(like this initialDoc: "GettingStarted.pdf") it was not working how to resolve this.

```
<head>

    <meta content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type">

    <script src="js/html5/external/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type=
    "text/javascript">

    </script>

    <script src="js/WebViewer.min.js" type="text/javascript">

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
    var viewerElement = document.getElementById('viewer');
    var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
    type: "html5mobile",
    path: "js/",
    documentType: "pdf",
    initialDoc: "GettingStarted.pdf",
    //documentId: "GettingStarted",
    enableAnnotations: true
    //streaming: false
    }, viewerElement);
    });
    </script>
    <title>
    </title>
</head>

<body style=
"width:100%;height:100%;margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">

    <div id="viewer" style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For PDF file viewing: The .pexe, .nmf, .res and .mem file extensions might need to be added to your server's allowed mime types list. Please consult your server's manual on how to add the following entry to its mime types list.

The following mime types should be added:

Extension: .res, Mime type: application/octet-stream
Extension: .pexe, Mime type: application/x-pnacl
Extension: .nmf, Mime type: application/octet-stream
Extension: .mem, Mime type: application/octet-stream